# What is ASP.NET Web API put?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I saw a wrong explanation in an explanation video, but it was explained correctly in the video.

This is the code:

```
public User Put([FromBody] User user)
{ 
    var editedUser = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id)
    editedUser.Firstname = user.Firstname;
    editedUser.Lastname = user.Lastname;

    return to user;
}
```

This was an API video. First, he defined fake data as `_users` using the bogus library. He created the model class `User`, so there is nothing wrong with the model. But then he wrote the put method as above and the data was updated. Isn't this code wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

Comment: Explain why you think it's wrong and what it should be instead. What exactly do you mean by *"the data was updated"*. The code modifies an object so of course that object is modified. There's no saving of that change to a database but then there's no specific indication that the data is coming from a database in the first place. What exactly happens that you don't expect or doesn't happen that you do?

Comment: *"I saw a wrong explanation in an explanation video, but it was explained correctly in the video"*. That is an outright contradiction, so it's hard to know what you're actually trying to say.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The video I'm talking about is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxvcD5fXFuA. And its 17:38th minute. I think return edited user instead of return user. However, the lecturer does not realize that he made a mistake in the rest of the video. What do you think?